# Извлечь определенный данные в заданном промежутке в большом тексте

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Дан длинный текст, из которого надо извлечь определенные данные ограниченные символами `[` и `]`.

Пример:

```
string = "[(< 0x7efd951a8b00 tags 0:0:6> payload [1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0]>, < consts 0, 4294967295>> payload [943317]>), (<ObjectName value object at 0x7efd94ed49e8 tagSet <TagSet object at 0x7efd951a8b00 tags 0:0:6> payload [1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0]>,"
```

Мое решение:

```
st = string.split("payload [")[1].split("]>")[0]
print(st)
```

В этом примере извлекается только 1 значение. Kак извлечь все?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение, например:

```
import re
string = "[(< 0x7efd951a8b00 tags 0:0:6> payload [1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0]>, < consts 0, 4294967295>> payload [943317]>), (<ObjectName value object at 0x7efd94ed49e8 tagSet <TagSet object at 0x7efd951a8b00 tags 0:0:6> payload [1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0]>,"
st = re.findall('payload \[(.*?)\]',s)
print(st)
```

вывод:

```
['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0', '943317', '1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0']
```

Comment: Спасибо но получается так ['[(< 0x7efd951a8b00 tags 0:0:6> payload [1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0]', '[943317]', '[1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0]']  а надо так 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0   943317     1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0

Comment: @Dima у вас 4 открывающих скобки и 3 закрывающих. вы можете сформулировать более строго, что же вам надо?

Comment: мне надо выделить текст между payload [ И ]> и так во всем тексте. Тут использование спецсимвола \ не подходит ибо есть текст с одной стороны и второй символ с другой

Comment: должно получится так 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0    943317   1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0

Comment: @Dima обновил, посмотрите

Comment: Виктор спасибо Вам. Да действительно похоже, но может подскажите как выделить чистый текст и присвоить их к примеру а = 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
в = 943317        с = 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0

Comment: @Dima обновил еще раз. А уж присвоить для a, b, c сделайте самостоятельно =)

Comment: @Dima если ответ вам подходит, тут есть галочка "принять"